# Accessing Excel 2013 File in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am developing an ASP.NET application. I have an Excel 2013 file named ExcelApp and i have also added in my project. I can not access the file.

Here is my DAL class:

```
public string ExcelConnection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Nimit\ExcelApplication.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml';HDR=YES"; 
    OleDbDataAdapter DbAdap;
    DataTable dt;

    public DataTable Get_ExcelSheet()
    {
        OleDbConnection DbCon = new OleDbConnection(ExcelConnection);

        DbAdap = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]",DbCon);
        dt = new DataTable();
        DbAdap.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
```

My cs file code:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DAL obj = new DAL();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack == true)
        {
            Get_Data();
        }
    }

    void Get_Data()
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = obj.Get_ExcelSheet();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

My debugger shows the error while executing this line:

```
DbAdap.Fill(dt);
```

The exception is:

[image]

Comment: What is `[ExcelApp$]` ?

Comment: Check your table name is correct

Comment: @Serv ExcelApp$ is my excel file name..

Comment: @Zaki I have changed the ExcelApp$ to Sheet1$, but the same exception is coming again..The Sheet1$ is showing in place of ExcelApp$

Comment: Try SELECT Name, Email_ID FROM [Sheet1$] check this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/509179/Read-Excel-File-into-DataSet-in-ASP-NET-Using-Csha

Comment: i tried this also. hey i made some changes...i am about to edit my program within 2 minutes, please help me

Comment: @Zaki what should i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my question. Here is my code:

```
public class DAL
{
    OleDbDataAdapter DbAdap;
    DataTable dt;

    public DataTable Get_ExcelSheet()
    {
        OleDbConnection DbCon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Nimit\\ExcelApplication.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;\"");

        DbAdap = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]",DbCon);
        dt = new DataTable();
        DbAdap.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

I simply provide my connection string in my OleDbConnection. Thats it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should read again the exception. There is a clear message why this code fails you... I'll give you a hint:

> Additiona information: The "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.40' provider is not registered on the local machine

Fix that and it should work.

Comment: I installed the Office system driver  and i also follow the link

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/509389/27Microsoft-ACE-OLEDB-12-0-27plusproviderplusisplu

but the error continues

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0** use **Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0**

And also try with passing relative/absolute path.

Note: In my connection string I am passing filePath+fileName

```
connString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\";",
                                       filePath + fileName)
```

Comment: and here is useful reference to connection strings: http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2013/

Comment: Please find ACEOLEDB.DLL dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE12\ If does not exists you need to download and register with windows

Comment: @Dawid The exception is coming after following your link named Could not find installable ISAM

Comment: @Siddu i found the dll file in the location.

Comment: @Siddu do i add the reference of this dll file in my project?

Comment: Check your MS Application if installed as x64 or 32 bit environment. On Web App Server (IIS Manager) try to change your application pool on advance settings >> Enable 32 bit Application - set True/false then restart the application. On windows app try to publish in x86/64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

First Check out your connection string; it must contain reference for your Excel "ExcelApp.xlsx".
Second the ExcelApp$ in the select must refer the sheet name and not the Excel file name.

hope you resolve with this

Comment: I changed the table name in Select statement as Sheet1$, but the same exception is coming..

Answer (score 0):

When some cases, require installing 32 bit MDAC Plugin intent to solution of problem. I did that and solved the problem.