# Uploading latest version of Excel data like 2013 into SQL Server table without installing Access database engine

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, excel-2013

I get this error

> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

I get this error when I try to upload Excel 2013 data into a SQL Server table using .NET. I need to solve this error without installing the Access database engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thank you for your response Mr.ArunGeorge. I solved my question .

I would use EPPlus and SqlBulkCopy for this. It saves having to install anything on the server, like Office or the Access database connector (ACE), and SqlBulkCopy is a very fast way to insert data into SQL Server from C# (or VB) code. Also, EPPlus will create an Excel workbook in memory from a stream which means that you don't have to save the uploaded Excel file to the server, thereby saving you from having to mess about with file permissions or clearing out saved files that are no longer needed.

You can get EPPlus from Nuget (install-package EPPlus). Once you have it, here's a very simple Web Forms example showing how to use it. First, the aspx file which only has a FileUpload and a Button:


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="Upload" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" />
</asp:Content>

Then the code-behind:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack && Upload.HasFile)
    {
        if(Path.GetExtension(Upload.FileName).Equals(".xlsx"))
        {
            var excel = new ExcelPackage(Upload.FileContent);
            var dt = excel.ToDataTable();
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Server=.;Database=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
            {
                var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn);
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "YourTable";
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    //assumes that the Excel column names match the import table exactly
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
                }
                conn.Open();
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            }
        }
    }
}

You will need the following additional using statements at the top of the file:

using OfficeOpenXml;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
And you will need the following extension method. Just create a class file called ExcelPackageExtensions and paste the following code into it:

public static class ExcelPackageExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable(this ExcelPackage package)
    {
        ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (var firstRowCell in workSheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, workSheet.Dimension.End.Column])
        {
            table.Columns.Add(firstRowCell.Text);
        }
        for (var rowNumber = 2; rowNumber <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row; rowNumber++)
        {
            var row = workSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1, rowNumber, workSheet.Dimension.End.Column];
            var newRow = table.NewRow();
            foreach (var cell in row)
            {
                newRow[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
            }
            table.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
        return table;
    }
}
You obviously need to change the connection string and table name to suit your needs, and if you have a mismatch between column names in the Excel file and the database (or don't have a header row in the Excel sheet) you will have to map columns individually instead of generically like I have here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option - https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/moving-data-from-excel-to-sql-server-10-steps-to-follow/

Another option would be to use OleDbConnection to read data from the excel file and then insert that data to the sql server -[Accessing Excel 2013 File in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247019/accessing-excel-2013-file-in-asp-net)